# How do I follow .Net Native cryptic stack-trace?

Tags: c#, exception, stack-trace, .net-native

Since UWP requires .Net Native (which is very welcome), I'm getting cryptic stack-traces now. This is the exception reported by people using my app:

```
System.InvalidCastException: InvalidCast_Com 
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x429e9d 
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x47d878 
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x48455a 
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x499043 
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x498fb7 
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x5ea468 
at SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x5ea418 
// this goes on...
```

I understand there's an invalid cast somewhere... but I need to know what `SharedLibrary!<BaseAddress>+0x429e9d` is pointing to.

Is there a way to find where these links point to?

Comment: You need the .pdb file of the library in question.  I haven't used .NET native, but I would assume it generates pdb files just like other compilers.

Comment: Thanks Bryce, I did find a few .pdb files in the bin/release directory. How do I query the files with the addresses above?

Comment: It's critical that your pdb file be the same one that was compiled with that exact executable.  I think there's a way to attach Visual Studio to a dump file from a crash if you have one, but if all you have is a text error report, I have no clue how to correspond that text to the binary pdb format.  You'll probably have to do some Googling on the topic.

Comment: have you found a good answer to that yet?

Comment: Not yet. I doubt this is gonna be easy. Maybe the .Net Native team will create a tool in the future to help us map these addresses.

Comment: Have you tried turning all exceptions on in the debug menu, just to see if it will show you exception directly?

Comment: @Netferret, these exceptions are thrown in the wild, not on my local development machine. The exception stacktrace comes from our logging/reporting that occurs when an `UnhandledException` is raised in the app.

Comment: I would write out any values sent to any 3rd party libraries via method parameters to a log then try and recreate the problem with a unit test for each one and run it on the target machine as well.  So for a random example 

var mytest = Convert.ToDateTime("value from log - this will throw as exception"); 

then you can see where the exception is actually triggered and investigate from there.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool in GitHub that can decipher .Net Native stack traces into human readable format.

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx-tools/tree/master/src/StackParser

Comment: StackParser has transformed `at Signal-Windows!<BaseAddress>+0xfd2403` to `at Signal-Windows!RuntimeFunctionSection+0x28403`. Am I missing .pdbs, or is this the desired output?

Comment: Sounds like a PDB problem ... are you sure you are feeding the tool with the matching PDB?